# Get JNI Signature for methods of nested classes

Tags: java, command-line, java-native-interface

Lets say I have a class called Scope that has a nested class called Variable, how exactly do I use `javap -s` to get the JNI signatures of the classes inside? I've tried doing

`javap -classpath <classpath> -s Scope$Variable`

, but this does not seem to work. It seems to just get me the same information as if I only typed "Scope" rather than "Scope$Variable".

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running `javap` in a Linux/Unix environment, then the `$` will be interpreted by the shell and not by `javap`. Therefore it mus be escaped. Simplest solution would be:

```
javap -classpath <classpath> -s 'Scope$Variable'
```

Without the quotes the shell (I assume a *sh offspring) will try to substitute the `$Variable` part with the contents of the environment variable `Variable`. I assume that no such variable exists and there fore nothing (as in "empty string") is substituted. Hence `javap` sees only

```
javap -classpath <classpath> -s Scope
```

If you are running the command from Windows, then this is not an issue, because the magical character would be `%`.

BTW: I don't know why JNI is involved here.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me: `javap -s com.oracle.net.Sdp$SdpSocket`:

```
Compiled from "Sdp.java"
class com.oracle.net.Sdp$SdpSocket extends java.net.Socket{
com.oracle.net.Sdp$SdpSocket(java.net.SocketImpl)   throws java.net.SocketExcept
ion;
  Signature: (Ljava/net/SocketImpl;)V
}
```